# Removing A Stripped Light Fixture Dome

Tags: light-fixture

When removing dome light fixture, very tight. I did loosen it, but now it is stripped.(just keeps turning) , Short of taking a hammer to break the dome, how do you remove It is loose enough to pry open a little , but I cannot get anything to hold the loose adapter.

Comment: No way at all to help you without a photo of the fixture. There are thousands of fixtures out there.

Comment: Thanks. I will try to add a photo. I do not know if I can, but it is a flush mounted ceiling light fixture dome (circular

Comment: I am with Speedy Petey need pics.

Comment: Sorry. I took the picture, but I cannot download it to this site or off phone (old school ,Alcatel 3932 (flip) Sorry . I think I am just going to break fixture

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that the whole light fixture is turning when you try to unscrew the glass globe? If so that means the base of the light has pulled away from one of the two screws that hold the fixture to the ceiling.

Comment: I just wanted to let you know that the problem has been fixed (without breaking the globe) I got enough room to insert a 6" crescent wrench and hold nut while turning to remove globe. Thanks for responses.

Comment: Way to go. Glad it worked out for you.